# How can I apply NMS (non-maximum suppression) on multiple images from a dataloader efficiently (PyTorch)?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, computer-vision, object-detection

I have the following function defined for non-maximum suppression (NMS) post processing on my predictions.

At the moment, it is defined for a single prediction or output:

```
from torchvision import transforms as torchtrans  

def apply_nms(orig_prediction, iou_thresh=0.3):
    
    # torchvision returns the indices of the bboxes to keep
    keep = torchvision.ops.nms(orig_prediction['boxes'], orig_prediction['scores'], iou_thresh)
    
    final_prediction = orig_prediction
    final_prediction['boxes'] = final_prediction['boxes'][keep]
    final_prediction['scores'] = final_prediction['scores'][keep]
    final_prediction['labels'] = final_prediction['labels'][keep]
    
    return final_prediction
```

where I then apply it to a single image:

```
cpu_device = torch.device("cpu")

# pick one image from the test set
img, target = valid_dataset[3]
# put the model in evaluation mode
model.to(cpu_device)
model.eval()
with torch.no_grad():
    output = model([img])[0]
 

nms_prediction = apply_nms(output, iou_thresh=0.1)
```

However, I'm not sure how I can do this efficiently for a whole batch of images from a dataloader:

```
cpu_device = torch.device("cpu")
model.eval()
with torch.no_grad():
  for images, targets in valid_data_loader:
    images = list(img.to(device) for img in images)
    
    outputs = model(images)
    outputs = [{k: v.to(cpu_device)for k, v in t.items()} for t in outputs]
    #DO NMS POST PROCESSING HERE??
```

What would be the best approach? How can I apply the above defined function for multiple images? Would this be best done in another for loop?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the *Generic Trnasform* paragraph in the torchivision doc [page](https://pytorch.org/vision/0.8/transforms.html#generic-transforms) you can use `torchvision.transform.Lambda` or work with functional transforms.

Here is an example with `Lambda`

```py
nms_transform = torchvision.transforms.Lambda(apply_nms)
```

Then, you can apply the transform with the `transform` parameter of your dataset (or you can create your custom dataset class, as well):

```py
dset = MyDset(..., transform=torchvision.transforms.Compose([torchvision.transforms.ToTensor(), nms_transform()])
```

Comment: thanks, would this assume that I save the outputs/predictions as a new dataset?

Comment: Yes. Otherwise, you can just apply the function online during evaluation, during the for loop, as you suggested. The choice really depends on what you are developing (an application, a research project, etc.)

Comment: ok well during evaluation, atm I'm only able to apply it when I have a batch size of 1...I think this may be ok but it's inefficient. I'm just struggling to understand how I can do it with a batch of images with the function I defined above

Comment: The point is that I don't think you can stack the bounding boxes of different images together otherwise you may encur in wrong computations. Perhaps you can get a speed up, if you use a positive `num_workers` parameter in the `DataLoader` along with a custom `collate_fn`. Check the [DataLoader](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.DataLoader) class for more details.